# 2D quantum well energy spectrum (analytical vs numerical)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, approximations, eigenvalue

I am trying to understand the energy spectrum difference between the analytical and the approximated solution for a quantum well.
The particle is inside a box with domain $\Omega=(0,0)$X$(1,1)$. For this I have $\hbar = m = 1$ and the energy is given analytically by $E_{m,n}=\frac{\pi^2}{2}(n^2 + m^2)$

My approximation is done using finite differences with a grid of $60$X$60$. The eigenvalues that I'm getting with the exact solution are always positive whereas the eigenvalues I'm getting with the approximated solution are always negative.

I am not familiar with quantum mechanics. That said, can you help me understand this? What can be happening, is it a big error due to the approximation? Where or what can I think of to try to understand these results?

I hope the question and the problem are well stated if not just tell me, probably I missed some important data and/or assumption.

**UPDATE**

Here I paste the code used to do this little simulation

```
clc;
xO = 0;
xL = 1;
N = 60;
%First build the matrix for a 1D-mesh
h = (xL - xO) / (N-1);
H = diag( (-2/h^2)*ones(1,N), 0 ) + ...
    diag( (1/h^2)*ones(1,N-1), 1 ) + ...
    diag( (1/h^2)*ones(1,N-1), -1 );
%Using the tensor product build the matrix for the 2D-mesh
H = kron(H, eye(N)) + kron(eye(N), H);
H = (-1/2) .* H;

%Compute the eigenvalues E and eigenvectors Psi
[Pcomp, Ecomp] = eig(H);

fEexac = @(m,n) ((pi^2)/2) * (n^2 + m^2);
Eexac = [];
for n=1:N
    for m=1:N
        Eexac((n-1)*N+m,(n-1)*N+m) = fEexac(n,m);
    end
end

%Plot energy from analytical vs computed
figure(1); hold on;
plot(1:N^2, sort(diag(Eexac)), 'b', 1:N^2, sort(diag(Ecomp)), 'r');

%Plot discretized energy spectrum
figure(2); hold on;
plot(1:40, diag(Ecomp(1:40,1:40)), 'r');

%Compare lowest 300 eigenvalues (exact and computed)
figure(3); hold on;
x = 1:300;
plot(1:300, sort(diag(Eexac(1:300,1:300))), 'b', ...
    1:300, sort(diag(Ecomp(1:300,1:300))), 'r');
```

Comment: Could be a simple offset in the ground state energy. Check the differences between your eigenvalues first and see if they are the same for the exact and discrete solution. The analytical solution has energy 0 at the bottom of the well. Is the same true for your grid? Also, maybe you have a sign error in your Hamiltonian?

Comment: Indeed I checked my Hamiltonian, there was a minus sign missing. Now both are positive. But I still see a big difference between the approximated eigenvalues and the real ones, [see image](http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/5375/99321444.png) any tips you can give, I don't want the answer but I don't know where to start to understand this.

Comment: Hm, at this point it would help to post your code, or at least the relevant portions of it.

Comment: Are you following a particular text, that would help us understand your code? I just want to check something. Quantum wells have a confining potential only in one dimension, the others are "in plane" unconfined directions.  For example, if this was 2D box of semiconductor material I wouldn't expect 1D quantum well solutions. Maybe this could be an explanation? Or maybe it's just a case if using different definitions.

Comment: Nope, I'm not following a particular text and as I said I'm not familiar with quantum mechanics it was more oriented to understand the application of eigenvalues and eigenvectors on numerical approximations.

Comment: Sorry, this is an extremely confusing question. First of all, the physics part is trivial: the eigenvalues are written in your question and the eigenstates are simply $\sin Kx\cdot \sin Ly$, products of standing waves. So your question is really a programming one about your code that is trying to reproduce these simple solutions analytically. It's very confusing what you graphed on the chart you added: what are the axes?

Comment: A numerical calculation doesn't immediately assign values of $K,L$ or equivalently $m,n$ to a numerically found eigenstate on the lattice (solution of the partial differential equation), how does your short code is supposed to attach the labels? Or what you're doing? You implicitly seems to assume that "it's clear what we want the program to do" but it's surely not clear to me. Moreover, with a 60 x 60 grid, the simulation is clearly OK only for $m,n\ll 60$. I would only "roughly trust" those with $m,n\leq 10$, i.e. about 50 eigenvalues. Does it explain your results?

Comment: Nope it is not a problem about programming I am sure the programming is well, at least for what I think I have to do. The problem is how to interpret the eigenvalues of the result after the approximation. You say that the numerical calculation does not assign values to $m,~n$, mmm... I am not sure what does that means. $i_{th}$-eigenvalue vs. its corresponding energy-value.